# View objects id

Tags: android, view

I have several objects in an activity and I would like to check their id before I perform any actions on them. However I'm not sure how to go about it, I tried :

```
 if (v.getId().contains("empty")){
```

but that gives an error and then I tried

```
if (v.getId() == "[attr^=empty]"){
```

and that is also wrong. To be honest I am aware that both of these don't use proper assignments and so on but I'm really lost on how to check whether an id contains a certain substring.... I would appreciate it if someone could help

PS: v is a View object

Comment: `v.getId()` returns an int. you cannot compare an `int` with a `string`.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but I'm getting confused how it works. What I mean is, when you define an object for example an ImageView in an xml file you give it an id (for example: android:id = "@id/empty1") and when you use the view object in the java/activity you first need to define it as a view object (View emptySpot = findViewById(R.id.empty1)) so how can I check what a certain id starts with without treating it as a string? should I apply string.valueof()? ...

Answer (score 0):

`v.getId()` returns an integer. In order to check `id` before doing something, I'd recommend something like:

```
switch (v.getId()){
     case R.id.ViewElement1:
          //do something here
          break;

     case R.id.ViewElement2:
          //do something here
          break;

     case R.id.ViewElement3:
          //do something here
          break;
}
```

What this code does is that it gets the Id of your View then compares it through a switch-case block. If the id taken from `v.getId()`, the code in the case block executes. The `break;` is important, otherwise, the code in the cases below the one executed will also run. You can also do this for an if-else if that fits your style more.

If you want to fetch the id as a string, you can try:

```
String ResourceIdAsString = v.getResources().getResourceName(v.getId());
```

and then you can do your if contains operations on the String object.

Comment: this is what I'm currently doing and I have a default case where I would like to apply the same action to all other views with an id starting with empty but I don't know how to check for only a part of an id or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve. So there's some overview of how `id` works.

First you have to `id` all of your views in `xml` like:

```
<TextView
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:weight="match_parent"
    android:id="@+/myTextView" />
```

Then in your JAVA code use a switch case like:

```
switch(view.getId()){

  case R.id.myTextView1:

   break;

}
```

If you have some views that do same thing you can use them like:

```
switch(view.getId()){

  case R.id.myTextView1:
  case R.id.myTextView2:
  case R.id.myTextView3:
  case R.id.myTextView4:
       perfomeSomeAction();
   break;

}
```

Comment: idk how your answer is different from mine. You even forgot the `break;` statements in your last code block.